# Unable to set <xsl:choose> xsl condition inside <a> tag. Expression returns empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add a condition within a link that looks something like this.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
  <xsl:value-of select="./Data[@Name='Title']"/>
  <div class=""></div>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/Properties/Data[@ID='ISSOCIAL']/Option[@Selected='true']/Value = 1">
        pull-right down
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        pull-right
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Unfortunately the class inside the div tag looks like this `<div class="">`..empty.

However, if I was to just run the following without adding the condition inside the anchor tag it renders fine.

```
<div class=""></div>
<xsl:attribute name="class">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/Properties/Data[@ID='ISSOCIAL']/Option[@Selected='true']/Value = 1">
      pull-right down
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      pull-right
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Output looking like this `<div class="pull-right down"></div>`

Any ideas on why this is happening? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the attribute to the `div` then you need to put the `xsl:attribute` inside the `div`.

```
 <div>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/Properties/Data[@ID='ISSOCIAL']/Option[@Selected='true']/Value = 1">
        pull-right down
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        pull-right
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

As the question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 you can simply use

```
<div class="{if (/Properties/Data[@ID='ISSOCIAL']/Option[@Selected='true']/Value = 1) then 'pull-right down' else 'pull-right'}">..</div>
```

Comment: Looks I don't have access to XSL 2.0, I apologize I'll update my tags. Is there some way to do this with 1.0? Thank you.

Comment: See the edit, as I said, if you want to use `xsl:attribute` for the `div`, it belongs inside of the `div`.